# Spock is using real methods even though object is mocked

Tags: spock

In my app I use spock in version `2.0-M1-groovy-2.5`. I have a problem that even though I mokced a class I get npe from the internals of mocked method.

I have simple class called `ReactiveRestHighLevelClient` which looks like this

```kotlin
open class ReactiveRestHighLevelClient(val restHighLevelClient: RestHighLevelClient, private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) {
...
 fun index(indexRequest: IndexRequest): Mono<IndexResponse> {
        return Mono.create<IndexResponse> { sink ->
            restHighLevelClient.indexAsync( // < -- HERE I GET THE NPE EVEN THOUGH THE METHOD IS MOCKED
                indexRequest,
                object : ActionListener<IndexResponse> {
                    override fun onFailure(e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        sink.error(e)
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(response: IndexResponse) {
                        sink.success(response)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
...
}
```

I have class `ThreadModelElasticsearchService` which uses the `ReactiveRestHighLevelClient` and looks like this:

```kotlin
@Component
class ThreadModelElasticsearchService(
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
    private val reactiveElasticsearchClient: ReactiveRestHighLevelClient,
    private val extraFactsService: ExtraFactsService,
    private val customerDataService: CustomerDataService,
    rateLimiterRegistry: RateLimiterRegistry
) {
...
    fun save(operationId: String, threadModel: ThreadModel): Mono<ThreadModel> {
        val id = threadModel.threadId
            ?: ThreadModel.createKey(threadModel.partnerId, threadModel.customerId)
        return reactiveElasticsearchClient
            .index(
                IndexRequest(ThreadModel.INDEX, ThreadModel.TYPE, id)
                    .source(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(threadModel), XContentType.JSON)
            )
            .thenReturn(threadModel)
            .doOnNext { logger.info("[operation_id=$operationId] -- Saved : $it") }
            .onErrorMap { e ->
                logger.error("[operation_id=$operationId] -- Error calling elasticSearch", e)
                ElasticRepositoryError(e)
            }
            .rateLimit(elasticRateLimiter)
    }
...
}
```

Finally I have my test class called `ThreadModelElasticsearchServiceTest` which looks like this:

```java
class ThreadModelElasticsearchServiceTest extends Specification {

    ReactiveRestHighLevelClient reactiveElasticsearchClient = Mock()
     ... other mocks
ThreadModelElasticsearchService threadModelReactiveElasticsearchClient = new 
ThreadModelElasticsearchService(objectMapper, reactiveElasticsearchClient, extraFactsService, customerDataService, RateLimiterRegistry.of(RateLimiterConfig.ofDefaults()))

   def "should work"() {
        given:
            ThreadModel threadModel = new ThreadModel(...)
            reactiveElasticsearchClient.index(_ as IndexRequest) >> Mono.just(indexResponse)
        expect:
         threadModelReactiveElasticsearchClient.save("should-work", threadModel).block()
    }
```

When I run the tests I get execption like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.cb.elastic.search.api.elasticsearch.ReactiveRestHighLevelClient$index$1.accept(ReactiveRestHighLevelClient.kt:76)
```

which points to the body of the `index` method of the `ReactiveRestHighLevelClient` mock which is strange.

How to solve this ?

Comment: I do no speak Kotlin, but if you can provide me with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, I can take a look. I need something to build and run, first. So please update the question, then notify me by comment when the MCVE is read. Thanks.

Comment: Spock cannot mock final methods (which is the default with kotlin), you need to either open them or use something like https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable to do that for you.